# homomorphisms of abelian groups

Tags: abelian-groups

Describe:
1) Hom(Q/Z->Q)
2) Hom(Q->Q/Z)
Q rational numbers
Z integers

My thoughts
1) Q/Z i can describe as a/b, a,b coprime and smaller than 1. So I thought Hom(Q/Z->Q) I can describe as [f:a+N->b, N subgroup of Q/Z, a element of Q, b any element of a+N].

2) Hom(Q->Q/Z) = [f:a->a+N, where N any subgroup of Q/Z]

Is this correct?

Comment: No, not correct.  Also, this is not the correct forum for your question.  (Think about how 1/7 gets mapped in either case. What can f(1/7) possibly be?)

Comment: I got my fault in 1).  is 2) correct?

Comment: Good question, wrong website --- we do research at MO.

Comment: I don't think so.  In 2), what is f(22/7)? Your suggestion does not handle 22/7 as I read it.  You might ask on math.stackexchange instead.